# ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null, but it isn't

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have some Unity code that's meant to load a bitmap image from a file and add it to a mesh. But I'm getting an `ArgumentNullException` where I'm sure the argument isn't null.

The code which fails to load the image:

```cs
Texture2D img = new Texture2D(64, 64);
Debug.Log(">>" + img + "<<");
if (img == null) {
    Debug.Log("img is null");
}
img.LoadImage(File.ReadAllBytes($"{Application.persistentDataPath}/textures/{sl}"));
```

But on that last line, I get an `ArgumentNullException`.

The log output says this:

```
===============================================================
>> (UnityEngine.Texture2D)<<
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
Game:parseLine(String) (at Assets/Scripts/Game.cs:134)
Game:Awake() (at Assets/Scripts/Game.cs:78)
===============================================================
ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: tex
UnityEngine.ImageConversion.LoadImage (UnityEngine.Texture2D tex, System.Byte[] data) (at /home/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Modules/ImageConversion/ScriptBindings/ImageConversion.bindings.cs:35)
Game.parseLine (System.String line) (at Assets/Scripts/Game.cs:140)
Game.Awake () (at Assets/Scripts/Game.cs:78)ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
===============================================================
```

I have verified twice

1. `img` is a `Texture2D` object
2. It didn't print that `img` was null.

So the `img` is a `Texture2D` object that is not null, yet Unity seems to think it is.

Could someone please help me out on this one?

Comment: Did you try to load different image? Or did you try to set the image [manually with a byte array](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ImageConversion.LoadImage.html)?

Comment: Assign `File.ReadAllBytes`'s return value to a variable and check whether _it_ is `null`.

Comment: The exception is raised because the `File.ReadAllBytes($"{Application.persistentDataPath}/textures/{sl}")` is null not the `img` istance as others pointed out try to load a different file or/and put it to a variable so you can check if before the `img.LoadImage`

Comment: Nope, `File.ReadAllBytes` wasn't null. I printed out it's length (12342).

Answer (score -1):

The error is for `$"{Application.persistentDataPath}/textures/{sl}"` not the `img` variable. Check application permissions and file path.

Comment: Why is the stack trace inside `LoadImage`?

Comment: I assigned the return value of `File.ReadAllBytes($"{Application.persistentDataPath}/textures/{sl}")` to a variable called `bytes`, and printed out the length, and it said 12342, so it shouldn't be null.